# Syntax Django Website Error in URL name defining

Tags: python, django

I'm building a Django website and have a Syntax Error in a weird place. In urlpatterns, defining a name to my url.

I've tried this

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    ("", views.home, name="home")
]
```

And get this return

```
  File "C:\VsCodeProjects\my_project\home\urls.py", line 5
    ("", views.home, name='home')
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Maybe you meant '==' or ':=' instead of '='?
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but don't you need to wrap that with `path`? as in `path("", views.home, name="home")`? See [these docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls).

Comment: hahahaha, i'm forgetting the most basic. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `re_path(r...` commands.You can show this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/urls/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use square brackets [] instead of round parentheses () when defining your URL patterns because Django expects URL patterns to be in a list.

You should use the path() function to define your URL pattern. This function links a URL to a specific view function.

Check that the views.home function exists and is correctly imported. This function is responsible for handling the content of the webpage you're trying to display.

Be very careful about typos or syntax errors in your code. Even a small mistake can trigger a syntax error.

Here's the corrected code you can try:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home')
]
```